# How to search through Access macros?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

My Access database has a query which, I suspect, is called by macros or other queries. Is there any way to run a Find on the "code" of all the macros and/or queries, to look for a text string (in this case, the query name)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609548/ms-access-global-search-for-keyword-in-queries-forms-reports -- not sure if the 2010 version of FindAndReplace will work for 2013.

Answer (score 2):

this lists all the tables & queries:

```
SELECT IIf([type] = 5, "Query", "Table") AS [Object type]
    ,MSysQueries.Flag AS [Query type]
    ,MSysObjects.NAME
    ,MSysObjects.Id
    ,MSysObjects.Type
FROM MSysObjects
LEFT JOIN MSysQueries ON MSysObjects.Id = MSysQueries.ObjectId
GROUP BY IIf([type] = 5, "Query", "Table")
    ,MSysQueries.Flag
    ,MSysObjects.NAME
    ,MSysObjects.Id
    ,MSysObjects.Type
HAVING (
        (
            (MSysObjects.NAME) NOT LIKE "~*"
            AND (MSysObjects.NAME) NOT LIKE "Msys*"
            )
        AND (
            (MSysObjects.Type) = 1
            OR (MSysObjects.Type) = 4
            OR (MSysObjects.Type) = 6
            OR (MSysObjects.Type) = 5
            )
        )
ORDER BY IIf([type] = 5, "Query", "Table") DESC
    ,MSysQueries.Flag
    ,MSysObjects.NAME;
```

and this one lists each object and the queries that reference it:

```
SELECT [~MSys Tables & Queries].NAME AS [Object]
    ,MSysObjects.NAME AS [Used in query]
FROM [~MSys Tables & Queries]
LEFT JOIN (
    MSysQueries LEFT JOIN MSysObjects ON MSysQueries.ObjectId = MSysObjects.Id
    ) ON [~MSys Tables & Queries].NAME = MSysQueries.Name1
GROUP BY [~MSys Tables & Queries].NAME
    ,MSysObjects.NAME
ORDER BY [~MSys Tables & Queries].NAME
    ,MSysObjects.NAME;
```

I don't know how to search through Macros the same way.  Also, I'm not sure this always picks up objects used in Union queries.

I hope it gives you a place tro start.

Comment: Thanks. The second one gave me an error until I realized I needed to save the first one with the name "~MSys Tables & Queries".

Answer (score 0):

You can install a free Access Add-in [Access Dependency Checker](http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/), it can search strings thru all objects.