# Find Orphaned Database Objects

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a fairly complicated Access database with probably 40–50 queries. I am suspicious that some of the queries are not actually being used by anything. Is there a simple way to identify queries with no dependencies?

Comment: Simple?  No.  But it can be done with code.  I wrote a form that checks all tables and queries to see if they're referenced, and by what object.

Comment: you can also look at this response to a related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534326/how-to-search-through-access-macros/40534645#40534645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the menus: Database Tools> Object Dependencies  (varies with ms-access version)

Then select each Access object and refresh the dependencies check. It is a detective work.

Answer (score 1):

A tool I have found very useful is named 'Dependency Checker' and is a free Add-In that can be downloaded from http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/

In your case, once installed, run it, telling it to process all objects. When finished, click the drop-down for 'Find Special' and select 'Top/Unused Items'.

That will show you a list of all objects not referenced (pluse some 'noise')