# Finding out how a particular table in MS Access 2013 is populated

Tags: database, ms-access, dependencies

I have no experience with MS Access and have been asked to adapt MS Access Database for a customer. While doing it my supervisor wants me to figure out how a particular table (namely Planningfile in this case) has been filled. I tried Object dependency option and see some Queries which depend on the table but table itself does not depend on anything. Can I safely conclude that the data was enter manually? The main reason behind task is to avoid that the changes to structure of the table result in unwanted effects in some other parts of DB.

Help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Technically there is no way to know how the data got there.  It could have been imported from an external file.  It could have been copy and pasted from a spreadsheet.  It could have been inserted from temporary queries or queries that have since been changed or deleted.  There is no history mechanism that tells these sorts of details.

Comment: To ensure that there are no dependencies--or to find any dependencies--would require inspecting all queries, all VBA code, all access Forms--the VBA code and properties, for example Record Source, etc.  There could be external code which opens and writes to the database, so you should really consider the overall process and procedures for using the database to determine all possible means of data access and manipulation.  There is no single answer to such a question.

Comment: You are looking for a tool like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609548/ms-access-global-search-for-keyword-in-queries-forms-reports or https://www.devhut.net/2017/03/31/great-access-tools-find-and-replace/

Comment: Thank you all. I found by inspecting the VBA code files.